# Collaborating on fixing merge conflicts

Tags: git

Scenario:
Have a branch per (active) release in git,

Sequence is:

1. Bob makes changes to **R1** , commits, pulls **R1** and pushes **R1** to shared. Does not update **R2** on shared.
2. Jane makes changes to **R1** , commits.
3. Jane pulls **R1** from shared, deals with any conflicts, pushes **R1**.
4. *Go to **Step 1** again for a few times*
5. Jane gets told they need to bring **R2** up-to-date with fixes from **R1**
6. Jane pulls **R1** and **R2** from shared
7. Jane merges **R1** into **R2** locally. Merge conflicts in some area of code Bob's worked on.

Jane must fetch R2 from shared and handle the merge before she can push. But, she doesn't know what to do with Bob's changes.

Branches: **R1**, **R2**

```
 State of Shared Repository

 C1    - Bob
 |
 C2-+  - Jane
 |  |
 |  C3 - George
 |  |
 |  C4
 C5 |  - Bob
 |  |
 C6 |  - Jane  [R1]
    |
    C7 - Alice [R2]
```

Bob and Jane make changes to **R1**

Jane then wants to merge **R1** into **R2** to update the latest release. She solves the merge conflicts caused by her changes, however she doesn't know how to solve the conflicts cause by the changes Bob made.

Is there a way for Jane to use git and have Bob complete the merge?

I know ideally, Bob would have already merged his changes into **R2**, but suppose that isn't the case.

Possible workarounds (looking for something better)

1. Jane calls Bob over to her desk and Bob then resolves the conflict. Difficult when telecommuting
2. Jane saves conflicted file(s) and email to Bob, Bob fixes file and emails them back to Jane who then uses them in her commit.

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ See example of shared repository state above. Jane does a fetch. She wants the shared repository R2 branch to be updated with changes from R1. (eg. rolling in bug fixes from previous release into current release)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming Bob is blocked and Jane is anxious to move the issue along, Jane makes her best attempt at performing the merge.

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout R2
$ git merge --ff-only origin/R2
$ git checkout -b wip/R2-with-R1
```

Above wip stands for work in progress and is a convention that signals to the team that the tree and history are subject to radical change. Perhaps Jane really wants Bob to look over her resolutions that impact his code from R1 before integrating them into the baseline. (Note: this is an anti-pattern; a better approach would be to have automated tests that protect the desired behavior for the new code in R1 and allow developers other than Bob to merge confidently.)

Jane makes her best attempt at the merge.

```
$ git merge origin/R1
$ hack
$ git add ..
$ hack
$ git add ..
```

The wip/R2-with-R1 branch may even contain multiple checkpoint-style commits. Another good signal for each to contain would let the team know that it is speculative.

```
$ git commit -m 'FIXME: fix conflicts in Potrzebie'
```

When she is ready for Bob to look at it, she pushes it to a repository they can both see

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin wip/R2-with-R1
```

The `--set-upstream` option is there in case they need to work collaboratively on the new branch.

She then fires up her mail user agent.

```
To: Bob
From: Jane
Subject: speculative merge: wip/R2-with-R1

Bob: please look over my attempted merge in the subject branch and make
any necessary fixes that I may have overlooked.

I am particularly concerned about my Potrzebie conflict-resolutions.
Changes there always seem to bite us one way or the other.

Thanks,
Jane
```

After Bob’s fix and a fetch, the history will resemble

```
$ git lola
* 77d472c (origin/wip/R2-with-R1) fix by Bob
* ba1eb24 (HEAD, wip/R2-with-R1) FIXME: merge 2
*   80c207d FIXME: merge 1
|\
| * 2cf6ad4 (origin/R1, R1) R1 #2
* | 137b39d (origin/R2, R2) R2 #2
* | cb9a761 R2
...
```

At this point, Jane wants to preserve the merge but does not want to keep the ugly checkpoint commits. Squashing back to a merge commit requires just a bit of care.

```
$ echo Merge R1 into R2 | \
  git commit-tree origin/wip/R2-with-R1^{tree} \
  -p $(git rev-parse origin/R1) -p $(git rev-parse origin/R2)
84b177c498bc635612b66932f3d41096999e6d3f

$ git checkout R2
Switched to branch 'R2'

$ git merge --ff-only 84b177c498bc635612b66932f3d41096999e6d3f
Updating 137b39d..84b177c
Fast-forward
...
```

This leaves a history of

```
$ git lola
*   84b177c (HEAD, R2) Merge R1 into R2
|\
| | * 77d472c (origin/wip/R2-with-R1) fix by Bob
| | * ba1eb24 FIXME: merge 2
| | *   80c207d (wip/R2-with-R1) FIXME: merge 1
| | |\
| |/ /
| | /
| |/
|/|
* | 2cf6ad4 (origin/R1, R1) R1 #2
| * 137b39d (origin/R2) R2 #2
| * cb9a761 R2
...
```

and R2 now has by construction the same tree as Bob’s final tree.

Answer (score 3):

Other than Jane calls Bob over to her desk and reviews the changes at her computer, I don't think that this can be done in git.

When the merge is being resolved, you are creating a new commit and that is all happening locally.  Jane could make the merge and decide not to push the changes to the remote.  Until the merge commit has been pushed there is no way to know whether someone else merged into their copy of the remote.  Jane has to resolve the commits in order to complete the merge and that is only happening locally.

Having un-merged changes in the remote seems to be a bad idea anyway.  Supposing that I start working with the repo and pull changes before Bob finished resolving the conflicts.  What then?

The other way for Jane to know if she resolved the commits would be that she has a test suite to run.  Then she knows she made a mistake when tests start failing.

Comment: Yes, the "call over to the desk" protocol is what we've used in the past. But that's a little difficult with remote people.

Comment: I can appreciate that.  But if you have a question about the conflict, you need to get in touch with Bob somehow (e-mail, phone, skype, carrier pigeon).  But it will be outside of Git.  Otherwise resolve the conflicts as best you can and revert any changes that were incorrect with a later commit.

Comment: Yeah, was just hoping for someway to save the resolving work into git as maybe another branch, and then have Bob check that out and finish it.

Comment: This is why The Git Way recommends not having more than one person working on a branch at a time. Every contributor should have their own private branch to work on.

Answer (score 3):

We are in a similar situation.

Here's the way which we have found somehow work after a few different failed aproaches.
The point was how to share the conflicted hunks over remote repository.

1. Jane creates two branches from the tip of R2 and merge R1 onto them
   with a set of 'complementary' merge strategies;

   ```
   $ git branch wip/reference R2
   $ git checkout wip/reference
   $ git merge -s recursive -X theirs R1

   $ git branch wip/merging R2
   $ git checkout wip/merging
   $ git merge -s recursive -X ours R1
   ```
2. Now

   ```
   $ git diff wip/reference..wip/merging
   ```

   shows how R1 would have conflicted with R2 because '-s recursive -X ours/theirs' merge strategy "forces conflicting hunks to be auto-resolved cleanly by favoring our/their version."
3. Jane makes necessary changes on wip/merging so to solve the 'virtual' conflicts caused by her previous changes and leaves Bob's untouched.
4. Then Jane pushes wip/reference and wip/merging and call/IM/email/owlpost Bob to fetch them.
5. Bob checks the virtual conflicts and the halfway resolution Jane
   made and makes further changes against the conflicts his past change
   caused.
6. Then he merges wip/merging back to R2 if he feels everything looks good or optionally ask George/Alice to make further resolutions.

We are still under investigation how this affects later merges (i.e. if git rerere properly works).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the sequence of action correctly, it's as follows:

1. Bob makes changes to R1, commits, merges with his copy of R2 and pushes to shared.
2. Jane makes changes to R1, commits, merges with her copy of R2 and attempts to push to shared, but gets an out-of-date error.
3. Jane must fetch R2 from shared and handle the merge before she can push. But, she doesn't know what to do with Bob's changes.

In this situation, Jane and Bob could do the following:

1. Jane can create a branch on shared containing her changes to R2:

   ```
   git push origin R2:R2-from-Jane
   ```
2. Jane can then call/email/IM Bob and ask him to merge in his changes.
3. Bob sighs discontentedly at having to do this **again**, then resolves the merge with Jane's branch from the server:

   ```
   git fetch origin R2-from-Jane
   git checkout R2
   git merge R2-from-Jane
   git push
   git branch -d R2-from-Jane
   ```
4. Bob replies to Jane to let her know the merge is finished.
5. Jane removes her temporary branch from the server:

   ```
   git push origin :R2-from-Jane
   ```

   and then replies back to thank Bob.

*(Obviously, Bob could also handle deleting Jane's temporary branch on the server, but that didn't fit with the narrative as well.)*

Comment: I wrote a sequence explictly. I think the cause of this issue is Bob )and Jane) being lazy and not updating R2 everytime.